# Test class mixed DML Operation. Need to insert a User and a Lead in a test class and use this user in runAs to call the testee class's method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have the following test class:

```
@isTest
public class LeadsController_Test {
    private static User u;
    private static Lead l = new Lead();
    
    private static void createTestUser() {
        u = new User(
            ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Head'].Id,
            UserRoleId = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Name = 'SHORT TERM'].Id,
            LastName = 'last',
            Email = 'puser000@amamama.com',
            Username = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
            CompanyName = 'TEST',
            Title = 'title',
            Alias = 'alias',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US'
        );
        
        insert u;
    }
    
    private static void createLead() {
        l.Company = 'Breaker corp';
        l.Industry = '0001 Oil & Gas';
        l.Motivation__c = 'Testing';
        l.FirstName = 'Ackerman';
        l.LastName = 'Breaker';
        l.LeadSource = 'Broker';
        l.Country = 'Norway';
        l.City = 'Oslo';
        l.Email = 'Ackerman@Breaker.com';
        
        insert l;
    }
    
    public static testMethod void unsharedLeadFieldsControllerTest() {
        createTestUser();
        test.startTest();
        createLead();
        System.runAs(new User(Id = u.Id)) {
            LeadsController.checkDisplay(l.id);
        }
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Unfortuantely I am getting: `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): Lead, original object: User: []`.

I need to run as the user I am creating and I also need a lead. I tried putting `createTestUser()` inside and outside `test.startTest()`. The same I tried with `createLead()`.

Any ideas how to execute this test class without `MIXED_DML_OPERATION` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DML operations on certain sObjects, sometimes referred to as setup objects, can’t be mixed with DML on other sObjects in the same transaction. This restriction exists because some sObjects affect the user’s access to records in the org. You must insert or update these types of sObjects in a different transaction to prevent operations from happening with incorrect access-level permissions. For example, you can’t update an account and a user role in a single transaction.

There is a useful guide with an example, please go through and resolve MIXED_DML_OPERATION issue. click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm)

Comment: Thanks the @future part helped.

Answer (score 9):

There are couple of things to note here:

1. testMethod keyword is deprecated, you should is @IsTest annotation instead
2. To set up your test data for common methods, try to use @TestSetup annotation in a method that will include your common data before each individual test method execution, just like this:

   ```
   static void createTestDate() {  
        createTestUser();
        createLead();
   }
   ```
3. In order to **AVOID** the MIXED_DML_EXCEPTION error, you can either user an @Future annotation on your createTestUser() method, or you can wrap the execution of this method between a System.runAs(User) method. This User can be yourself for example, querying it like:

   ```
   User runAsUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getCurrentUserId()];
   ```

Comment: You don't even need to query for a user, `System.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getCurrentUserId())){ ... }` is sufficient.

Comment: I believe it's UserInfo.getUserId()